# Exact Cover variant: partition a family of subsets into exact coverings

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, np, set-cover

I have found that a problem that I'm analyzing is equivalent to the following variant of the Exact Cover problem:

> `Partition into $k$ Exact Covers`
>
> **Input**: A universe $U$ and a family $C\subseteq 2^U$ of subsets of $U$ in which each element $x\in U$ occurs in exactly $k$ subsets of $C$.
>
> **Question**: Can the family $C$ be partitioned into $k$ disjoint sub-families $C_1,C_2,\ldots, C_k\subseteq C$ such that each $C_i$ is an exact cover of $U$?

In other words, whereas Exact Cover asks us to find one sub-family that forms an exact cover, in this variant of the problem we need to find $k$ such families. Furthermore, if we represent the input by a graph in which each vertex represents a subset in $C$ and we add an edge if the two subsets have a non-empty intersection, `Partition into $k$ Exact Covers` can be seen to ask whether the resulting graph is $k$-colorable.

Is this problem already known to be NP-hard for some constant $k$? The case $k = 2$ is trivial to solve in polynomial time, so the case $k = 3$ would be of particular interest.

Comment: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/51587/5038